# Missing hard drive on df -H command on Centos 6.4

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-raid, centos6.4, df

I have 2*1000GB hard drives + 60GB SSD.
When I'm running `df -H` I'm getting "wrong" information about the server's hard drives.
**The output**

```
# df -H
Filesystem             Size   Used  Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/md1                78G    48G    26G  66% /
tmpfs                  4.2G      0   4.2G   0% /dev/shm
/dev/md0               520M    46M   448M  10% /boot
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `fdisk -l` report?

Comment: What makes you think the output is "wrong"? What output are you expecting? How does what you see differ from what you expected?

Answer (score 2):

`df` is for filesystems, not disks. As [skohrs](https://serverfault.com/users/128800) says, you'll want to use something like `fdisk` to deal with disks directly.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you don't have your 2*1TB HDDs mounted anywhere.  The only disk being shown is a MDRaid device of ~80 GB, presumably on your 80 (not 60) GB SSD.

To get your larger disks to appear, simply (format, if necessary, and) mount them.